# Find the most common max value & 2nd from Max value from a number of sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet, vlookup

Say I have 3 sheets with the same structure

**Season 1**

```
A   B       C
--------------- 
Pos Team    Pts
1   Team A  27
2   Team C  23
3   Team B  21
4   Team D  19
5   Team E  12
```

**Season 2**

```
A   B       C
--------------- 
Pos Team    Pts
1   Team B  24
2   Team A  20
3   Team D  19
4   Team E  17
5   Team C  15
```

**Season 3**

```
A   B       C
--------------- 
Pos Team    Pts
1   Team A  26
2   Team C  22
3   Team B  21
4   Team D  18
5   Team E  14
```

I want to find the most common team who comes 1st(Most Points). In this example, it would be `Team A`, as they have come 1st on two occasions and `Team B` only finished 1st once. And then I want to find the most common team who comes second, in this example, it would be `Team C`, as they came 2nd twice.

What would be the best way to go about this? I've got this far, to get the team who came first in each sheet, but I'm not sure how to use the result of each sheet to get the most common between all sheets...

```
=INDEX('Season 1'!B2:C6,MATCH(SMALL('Season 1'!A2:A6,1),'Season 1'!A2:A6,0))
```

The formula returns `Team A`

Comment: Have you looked at sumifs()?

Comment: Is it fixed at 3 sheets? What if different teams came in first in all 3 sheets--use Pts as a tie-breaker?

Comment: @jblood94 There will be a lot more than 3 sheets in the final spreadsheet, there is, of course, the likelihood that this may occur but I will cross this bridge if it comes to it.

Comment: If you have many sheets, the likelihood of getting at least 1 tie for the # of 1st, 2nd, 3rd...will be quite high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

```
=SORTN(QUERY({'Season 1'!A2:C6;'Season 2'!A2:C6;'Season 3'!A2:C6},"Select Col1,Col2,count(Col1) group by Col1,Col2 order by Col1,count(Col1) desc"),2^9,2,1,1)
```

- QUERY() to get count/each team/pos in descending order.
- SORTN to remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

For first place, this will automatically handle however many sheets you have (enter as an array formula):

`=INDEX('Season 1'!$B$2:$B$6,TRANSPOSE(MODE.MULT(IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Season "&TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SHEETS())))&"'!B"&ROW('Season 1'!B2)),'Season 1'!$B$2:$B$6)>0,ROW('Season 1'!$B$2:$B$6)),FALSE)))-ROW('Season 1'!$B$1))`

Fill down for 2nd, 3rd, etc. If you have a tie, you can select multiple cells (horizontally) when you enter the formula to give you all the ties.

This will count the number of ties for first place:
`=SUM(--(MODE.MULT(IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Season "&TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SHEETS())))&"'!B"&ROW('Season 1'!B2)),'Season 1'!$B$2:$B$6)>0,ROW('Season 1'!$B$2:$B$6)),FALSE))>0))`

Again, fill down for 2nd, 3rd...